# zeromq node.js file transfer

Tags: node.js, zeromq, file-transfer

We are planning to build an application similar to whats app, my technology stack is node.js,mongodb,zeromq for server side and android and  zeromq client in client side. I need to transfer the video/audio files, Is that a good choice to use zeromq for file transfer?. I had see filemq library of zeromq . There is any node.js library for the filemq? .

Thanks,
Shaiju